# Ubuntu on tablets and mobile phones

Tags: system-installation, phone, tablet

Is it possible to install Ubuntu on tablets and mobile phones by yourself?
Just as you can with computers ?

I'd be interested in having a go because then I could integrate all my stuff.

Thanks for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer NO, you can't just install Ubuntu on any phone or tablet, though there are a few that you can, I am sure in the future we will see many Touch roms for ARM devices

If you have an x86 phone or tablet (like a surface tablet) you can install the desktop version of Ubuntu on it with a USB as normal.

If you have an Android device (ARM), [you can port Ubuntu touch](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/), some high end devices already have roms on XDA and Nexus devices are supported.

If you have an `i`anything then, no you can't.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can on Android phones, however your phone should be rooted, otherwise it won't work (as far as I know). Never tried it although.

Here you can see the devices "officially supported": https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/devices/ but since Ubuntu is open source I'm pretty sure that there are some more devices that will work.